# Manipulating image within Indesign frame

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, basil.js

I am currently trying to figure out how to change the color of a bitmapped image within indesign using basil.js. Ideally I would like to place the image and use some sort fo post styling to change the color.

```
var myImage = image('image_0009_10.psd', 0, 0, width, height);
property(myImage, "fillColor", "RISOBlue");
```

Right now I am using fillColor but that only changes the color of the frame that the bitmap live within. Anyone got any ideas as to how to edit the contents of a graphic frame? Specifically a bitmap?

Comment: Hey fabianmoronzirfas & mdomino! Glad to be here. This was exactly what I was looking for. I ended up going mdomino's route but both answers are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fabianmoronzirfas is correct that you have to target the graphic of the image frame, I just want to suggest a slightly different syntax, which is a bit more basil-like to achieve the same thing:

```js
// @include ~/Documents/basiljs/basil.js

function draw() {

  var myImage = image('~/Desktop/someImage.psd', 0, 0);
  var myGraphics = graphics(myImage);
  property(myGraphics[0], 'fillColor', color(0, 0, 255));

}
```

Note the use of the `graphics()` function to get the actual graphics within an image rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to STO

You are currently setting the `fillColor` for the `Rectangle` that contains the image. You will have to select the image explicitly since it is a child object of that `Rectangle`. See:

- [`Rectangle`](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Rectangle.html)
- [`Images`](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Images.html#d1e240322)
- [`Image`](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign-latest/#Image.html#d1e236446)

The code below is tested with InDesign 14.0.1 and the current [Basil.js Develop version 2.0.0-beta](https://github.com/basiljs/basil.js/blob/9b3eae3316e643f7043baac237e4b2d380256c4d/basil.js)

```js
// @include "./basil.js"
function setup() {
  var doc = app.activeDocument;
  var imageFile = file(new File($.fileName).parent + "/img.bmp");
  var img = image(imageFile, 0, 0, 100, 100);
  img.images[0].fillColor = doc.swatches[4];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`graphics()` is perfect for this (as @mdomino mentioned) – but can also just grab that property of the image:

```
var myImage = image('image_0009_10.psd', 0, 0, width, height);
property(myImage.graphics[0], "fillColor", "RISOBlue");
```

Running `inspect(myImage)` will give a long laundry list of [available properties](https://www.indesignjs.de/extendscriptAPI/indesign8/#Rectangle.html#d1e189459).